# Java convert String to logic

Tags: java, string, parsing, logic

//having Java 7/8: 
    String logic = "123 OR 345 OR 678 NAND 901";

```
//Should evaluate something simililar to this: 
String test1 = "abc345678opq"; String test2 = "abc123901";

boolean isCheckOk1 = test1.contains("123") || test1.contains("345") || test1.contains("678") && !test1.contains("901");

boolean isCheckOk2 = test2.contains("123") || test2.contains("345") || test2.contains("678") && !test2.contains("901");

//where isCheckOk1 will be true

//and isCheckOk2 will be false;
```

Is there a generic way in Java a library to achive this?

Next level:

```
"123 OR 345 OR 678 NAND (901 AND 902)"
```

Thank you!

Comment: Do you want to parse a string containing the expression? Or do you just want to write the checks in Java, in a simpler syntax? For parsing, there are lots of reasonably simple parser generators.

Answer (score 1):

No, but you could use regex:

This:

```
boolean isCheckOk1 = test1.contains("123") || test1.contains("345") || test1.contains("678") && !test1.contains("901");
```

can be coded as:

```
boolean isCheckOk1 = test1.matches("(?!.*901).*(123|345|678).*");
```

---

The "extra points" could be coded as:

```
boolean isCheckOk1 = test1.matches("(?!.*901.*902)(?!.*902.*901).*(123|345|678).*");
```

---

Complicated logic would become unwieldy to do in regex.

Comment: If I could choose the way of implementation, yes. At this point I could simply use the logic instead of using regex. Or I would need a log-tring-to-regex-parser. And of cause, yes, it should handle more complicated logic.